# backbone, is there a side effect to triggering and event that there is no listeners for

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dom-events, marionette

So in backbone when we go to trigger and event lets say

```
this.trigger("do:something")
```

what if there are no listeners for this, obviously there are no errors thrown, but are there any side effects, otherwise I would need to wrap this in a conditional?

Comment: It is safe to trigger events without listeners

Answer (score 0):

Backbone definitely runs a bit of code on a `.trigger` call. If you're keen, you can actually follow what happens by looking at the source code: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js

The code could amount to a conditional early return if the object has no events defined. Or it could involve iterating over arrays of possible callbacks if any listeners have been added.

If you have a simple to check conditional then likely it would run faster than calling an empty `.trigger`, though the difference would surely never be noticeable.

If your conditional makes your code ugly, or is based on another backbone library method, I would skip it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no side effects as such but having such functions and given there are many can lead to slowing down the application.